# jQuery UI dialog box manual close

Tags: jquery, popup

I am using jQuery UI Dialog Box.

When I am clicking on a button the dialog box should open. When the dialog box is opened then whole body should be in a disable state. Like how exactly when we are using a popup. So for that I have used the below code.

Here is [Js Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nRQXA/) Link

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
<script>
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $("#popup").click(function(){
        $( "#dialog" ).dialog();
        $( ".parentDisable" ).show();
    });

    $(".parentDisable").click(function(){
        $( "#dialog" ).dialog('close');
        $( ".parentDisable" ).fadeOut(1000);
    });

    $(".ui-button-icon-primary").click(function(){
        $( "#dialog" ).dialog('close');
        $( ".parentDisable" ).fadeOut(1000);
    });

});
</script>
<style>
    .parentDisable{
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    background:#000;
    opacity:0.8;
    z-index:1;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog" style="display:none;">
  <p>This is the default dialog which is useful for displaying information. The dialog window can be moved, resized and closed with the 'x' icon.</p>
</div>

<div class="parentDisable" style="display:none;"></div>


<span id="popup" style="color:blue;cursor:pointer">Pop Up</span>


</body>
</html>
```

Here I have problem. When I am clicking on button pop up is opening and the whole body is covered with Black background.

Now the user should able to close in two types.

1. By clicking on close symbol in the popup.
2. By clicking on out side area of popup (On Black Background)

The 2nd way mentioned above is working fine. But in the first method when I am clicking on close symbol only the POPUP is getting close and the black background is remains same.

I have tried in some ways. But it has not worked.
Please give any suggestions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can subscribe to the [`close`](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#event-close) event of the dialog and hide your background:

```
$( "#dialog" ).on( "dialogclose", function( event, ui ) { 
    $( ".parentDisable" ).fadeOut(1000); 
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nRQXA/3/

**update**

Such functionality already exists in the dialog component:

```
  $( "#dialog" ).dialog(
    { 
       modal: true 
  });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nRQXA/23/

Comment: There is no `overlay` option in `$.dialog()` according to [official API documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/)

Comment: it was there for a while. Now it looks like removed. Thanks for update. I'll update the code.

Comment: @Samich It was [removed 3 years ago](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/commit/9241757d7ab493b8750656a9fa96391607ad00c4).

Answer (score 2):

Register your click event this way:

```
 $(document).on('click','.ui-button-icon-primary',function(){
        $( "#dialog" ).dialog('close');
        $( ".parentDisable" ).fadeOut(1000);
    });
```

Working [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nRQXA/22/)

Answer (score 1):

Register dialog with close event

```
$("#dialog").dialog({
         autoOpen: false,
         close: function (event, ui) {
             $(".parentDisable").fadeOut(1000);
         }
     });
```

Open it with open command

```
 $("#dialog").dialog('open');
```

Check out updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XUWuf/)

Answer (score 0):

```
  $("#dialog").dialog({
            buttons: { "Ok": function() {  $(this).dialog("close");}}
            });
```

Comment: You answer is not related to my question. But by your answer i got some info. Tanku.!